# Nerve of a groupoid is a cyclic set

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

On page 28 of the [COCTALOS](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/coctalos.pdf) lecture notes, it is written that a simplicial set is the nerve of a groupoid if and only if it is a cyclic set in the sense of Connes (I am understanding a presheaf on $\Lambda$  here).

However, I don't see how to prove this equivalence. In particular, I can't find a cyclic automorphism of the set of $n-$composable arrows in a groupoid.

Can anyone help me find this automorphism? I think (hope) that I could take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a groupoid ${\mathscr G}$ and $X_0\xrightarrow{f_1} X_1\to\ldots\to X_{n-1}\xrightarrow{f_n} X_n\in {\mathbf N}({\mathscr G})_n$ an $n$-simplex in its nerve, you also have $$X_n\xrightarrow{(f_n\dots f_1)^{-1}} X_0\xrightarrow{f_1} X_1\to\ldots\to X_{n-2}\xrightarrow{f_{n-1}} X_{n-1}\in {\mathbf N}({\mathscr G})_n.$$ Moreover, this association defines an automorphism of order $n$ on ${\mathbf N}({\mathscr G})_n$. Do you need more details?

Comment: Looks good, thanks! May I aks how you got this formula ?

Comment: Typo: in the displayed $n$-simplex, $f_1$ goes from $X_0$ to $X_1$.

Comment: @Pece: Thank you, corrected!

Comment: @Nitrogen: Imagine a $2$-simplex of ${\mathbf N}(\mathscr G)$ as a triangle with vertices $0,1,2$ and morphisms $0\to 1, 1\to 2, 0\to 2$ such that the morphism at the edge $0\to 2$ is the composition $0\to 1\to 2$. Now, the idea is to cyclically shift the indices of this triangle, i.e. to view it as a triangle with indices $i' := i+1$. For this, we need an arrow $1'\to 2' = 2\to 0$, and we take the inverse of the map we had at $0\to 2$, which was the composition $0\to 1\to 2$.